# Retrieving the Div id in a session variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need to know if there is a way where I can put the id(div id) into a session variable.

My code goes something like this

```
<div class='fieldRow'>Options </div>
<div id="abcde"></div>
<div class='Row'>

<?php
    $user_types->display();
    echo '<hr/>';
 ?>
 <!--<hr/>-->
</div>
```

I want to retrieve the value abcde in a session variable. Thanks for your help and time in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML/XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml)

Comment: Get it with javascript and pass it to an ajax script?

Comment: if your div id is pre defined the just add code $_SESSIOJN['div_id'] = $div_name if not then use body onload function then fetch value of div in add it to session using javascript ajax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create the ID inside PHP? Something like this:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $id = /* some code to create the id */ 'abcde';
  $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
?>

<div class='fieldRow'>Options </div>
<div id="<?php echp $id; ?>"></div>
<div class='Row'>

<?php
    $user_types->display();
    echo '<hr/>';
 ?>
 <!--<hr/>-->
</div>
```

Comment: This looks great but the id's are predefined

Comment: If Ids are predefined then you can preload them into the $_SESSION nyet?  If you give a little more information about what you are trying to achieve, you will get a better answer.